# how to disable privacy or anyother feature in edit profile form in userena?

Tags: python, django

I've tried many things but I just can't figure it out. 
I followed one from here, [django-userena removing mugshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984129/django-userena-removing-mugshot) but this isn't working for me. I tried one here https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/1mgk3b/adding_and_removing_custom_django_userena_form/ but this also isn't working. 
This is how I did it, 
In accounts/forms.py 
This is all I have.

```
from userena.forms import EditProfileForm

class EditProfileFormExtra(EditProfileForm):
    class Meta(EditProfileForm.Meta):
      exclude = EditProfileForm.Meta.exclude + ['privacy']
```

And inside accounts/urls.py
I have this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/edit/$', 'userena.views.profile_edit', {'edit_profile_form': EditProfileFormExtra}, name='userena_profile_edit'),

)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you deleted the `privacy` field from `profile_form.html`?

Comment: @doru, no i didn't touch profile_form.html because I just have     {{ form.as_p }} which I think includes privacy field